# Where is glibc's code for setjmp?

Tags: c, setjmp

I was interested in what exactly `setjmp` does at least in x86_64 linux, so I searched through `glibc`'s source code, but I cannot really find where the register saving is done. Could you explain what is going on here?

**setjmp.h**

```
extern int _setjmp (struct __jmp_buf_tag __env[1]) __THROWNL;
#define setjmp(env)     _setjmp (env)
```

**bsd-_setjmp.c**

```
int
_setjmp (jmp_buf env)
{
  return __sigsetjmp (env, 0);
}

libc_hidden_def (_setjmp)
```

**setjmp.c**

```
int
__libc_sigsetjmp (jmp_buf env, int savemask)
{
  __sigjmp_save (env, savemask);
  __set_errno (ENOSYS);
  return 0;
}

weak_alias (__libc_sigsetjmp, __sigsetjmp)
stub_warning (__sigsetjmp)
```

**sigjmp.c**

```
int
__sigjmp_save (sigjmp_buf env, int savemask)
{
  env[0].__mask_was_saved = (savemask &&
                             __sigprocmask (SIG_BLOCK, (sigset_t *) NULL,
                                            &env[0].__saved_mask) == 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it's written in assembly in one of the platform specific directories. Have you tried single-stepping with a debeugger through the glibc and observing what source files you hit?

Comment: It might be done internally within the compiler.

Comment: The x86_64 source can be [found here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/setjmp.S;h=774aaf1e8d9c918162a88cb1141fe4737969c4af;hb=HEAD).  It's written in assembly. If you move "up" a directory, you can find the source for other platforms too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setjmp` is a macro which calls `_setjmp`. For the x86_64 architecture, it's defined in `../sysdeps/x86_64/bsd-_setjmp.S`. `_setjmp` will then call `__sigsetjmp`, defined in `../sysdeps/x86_64/setjmp.S`; this function is strictly platform dependent and needs to be implemented in assembly.